# Why can I ping IP addresses from 127.0.0.1 to 127.255.255.254?

Tags: ipv4, ip, ping, icmp, loopback

I thought that the loopback IP address of my machine is `127.0.0.1`.

I do not understand why am I able to ping IP addresses until `127.255.255.254`.

Comment: I think your question is off-topic here, but I would like to tell you that the entire range 127.0.0.0/8 (127.0.0.1 - 127.255.255.254) is reserved for loopback purposes and they are always available. On most systems, `localhost` resolves to 127.0.0.1 which is the most commonly used IPv4 loopback address.

Comment: @HungTran Thank you for the information. So basically my own computer has many local IP addresses?

Comment: Yes, and the right term should be `loopback IP addresses`, NOT local.

Comment: @HungTran Thank you, I understand. So the computer can have an IP address on the NIC and that is the local IP address, the IP assigned to the NIC. The loopback is a separate IP address but it is not assigned to the NIC it is just an internal IP address that the computer uses to communicate with itself. Am I correct?

Comment: Basically, we can understand like that. You can read [more discussions here](https://superuser.com/questions/897699/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-my-assigned-ipv4-address).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The entire address block `127.0.0.0/8` is the block of loopback addresses for a host. There are RFCs that explain this.

The goes back at least as far as [*RFC 990, ASSIGNED NUMBERS*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc990):

> The class A network number 127 is assigned the "loopback" function,
> that is, a datagram sent by a higher level protocol to a network 127
> address should loop back inside the host. No datagram "sent" to a
> network 127 address should ever appear on any network anywhere.

[*RFC 1122, Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Communication Layers*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3):

> (g) { 127, }
>
> Internal host loopback address. Addresses of this form MUST NOT appear
> outside a host.

Also [*RFC 3330, Special-Use IPv4 Addresses*](http://RFC%203330,%20Special-Use%20IPv4%20Addresses):

> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback address. A datagram sent by a higher level protocol to an
> address anywhere within this block should loop back inside the host.
> This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback,
> but no addresses within this block should ever appear on any network
> anywhere [RFC1700, page 5].

Answer (score 1):

To answer the OP's Q: "why am I able to ping IP addresses until 127.255.255.254"? (which is a dup of https://serverfault.com/questions/360283/loopback-interface-on-linux-catches-all-loopback-traffic)

A: the early RFCs were ambiguous, Linux and apparently Windows interpreted them to mean "the host should respond on all loopback addresses. BSD - and thus macOS - use the "only 127.0.0.1/32" interpretation.

Aside: Linux's systemd relies on this behaviour - its `systemd-resolved` local stub listener receives requests via the loopback interface and filters out anything other than 127.0.0.53 or 127.0.0.54 (ref. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html). At no point are the IP addresses 127.0.0.53 or 127.0.0.54 configured on `lo`.

Comment: RFC 1700 was not the original source for the entire block being the loopback block. It goes back at least as far as RFC 990 ("_...a datagram sent by a higher level protocol to a network 127 address should loop back inside the host._") where it is clear that a packet sent to any address in the old Class A `127` (`127.0.0.0/8`) is to loop back inside the host. See my answer on this.

Comment: Ack; I'll amend the answer's second para to "The early RFCs were ambiguous, Linux and apparently Windows interpreted them to mean "the host should respond on all loopback addresses"; BSD - and thus macOS - use the "only 127.0.0.1/32" interpretation.

Comment: *systemd relies on this behaviour*: Why? It would also be possible that only the "used" addresses (127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.53 and 127.0.0.54) respond to an ICMP echo request - or even to implement TCP/IP in a way that `ping` is not supported for localhost at all.

Comment: Your last paragraph doesn't match the behaviour of systemd-resolved (v250.8) on my system. `systemd-resolved` `bind()`s only to those two specific addresses, so it never gets to see any other traffic going to 53/udp on the loopback interface. I have just verified that using `strace`.

Comment: TBH, I didn't reverse engineer this, rather I'm going mainly by a cursory examination of systemd's source: if I'm reading it right systemd-resolved has a "bind to interface and filter only valid addresses" approach. e.g. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v251/src/basic/socket-util.c#L1270, and https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v251/src/resolve/resolved-dns-stub.c There's also use of IP_FREEBIND in there too. So, "it's complicated" ;-) The main point I was trying to make was that at no point are the IP addresses 127.0.0.53 or 127.0.0.54 configured on the `lo` interface.